# Why do these statements have the opposite result?

Tags: vb.net, comparison

I'm trying to filter a list of objects, each of which has a calendar year as one of its values. The user types in a beginning year (e.g. 1920) and an end year (1940), and any object that has a year in between those two values is added to a list. So for each object in the whole list, I perform the following conditional:

```
If _end >= _nList(i).Year > _start Then
     filterList.Add(_nList(i))
End If
```

This returns false, however. But when I change it around to:

```
If _start < _nList(i).Year <= _end Then
      filterList.Add(_nList(i))
End If
```

This evaluates as true, and runs the code. `_nList(i).Year` is 1928, `_start` is 1920 and `_end` is 1940. Logically, the two statements should be equivalent:

```
1940 >= 1928 > 1920
1920 < 1928 <= 1940
```

But for some reason they aren't in this case. What have I missed here?

Comment: Are you attempting two size-checks at once? Why don't you seperate them as different if statements instead? `_end >= _nList(i).Year and _nList(i).Year > _start`

Comment: I didn't even realise this was valid syntax. How about rewriting it with 'and's ?

Comment: The first equates to `(1940 >= True)`, the second to `(1920 <= True)`  See [If...Then...Else Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why the second if statement works?

Comment: @Steven That should be `AndAlso`, not `And`.

Comment: Really, microsoft should make `Option Strict` default now. Everyone who wants to use unsafe code is free to change that setting.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with separate if statements and And, and it works fine, I guess this syntax doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn Option Strict On. It will explain the problem.

```
If a < b < c Then
```

It check "a < b" which returns a Boolean value. Then compares that Boolean value with "< c" which isn't possible. It will convert that Boolean returned by "a < b" to an integer then compare that value with "[converted Boolean] < c". That is not want you want, this error will be displayed with Option Strict On.

**You need to separate into two comparison.**

```
If _end >= _nList(i).Year AndAlso _nList(i).Year > _start Then
```

The way you did might work in some language but that's not how vb.net is.

Comment: _"that's not how vb.net is"_ that doesn't work in most languages including all C derivatives and java. Where does it work?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't know ... I didn't want to say "it never works in any language". Maybe I could phrase it differently.

Comment: Are you sure guys that it doesn't work on python? I'm pretty sure i saw something similar to this in py

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I was right! `If a < b < c` is working on python

Comment: @Simo i haven't said that it doesn't work in any language. I was just interested where.

Comment: on python you can do pretty much everything. this is why is cool and bad at the same time

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you could use much shoerter syntax using LINQ extension methods:

```
Dim _filteredList = _list.Where(New Func(Of C, Boolean)(Function(i As C) As Boolean
                                                                Return i.Year > _start AndAlso i.Year < _end
                                                            End Function)).ToList()
```

where `C` is class of objects in your list.

Comment: I love this magical LINQ which provides short elegant solutions to VB.NET problems. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I've accepted the other answer which most directly answers the question, but if I could award you a special bonus point for the LINQ I would happily :')